# Detecting "Connection was Reset" in an iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, networking, iframe

I work on a long-running application that gets deployed in chrome in kiosks with arbitrarily bad connectivity. It's a standard web-app, and we serve various kinds of content into these kiosks, sometimes using iFrames to load fairly complex interactive assets.

Every once in a while, we see that the interactive asset simply displays a chrome error, "the connection was reset", as the content of the iframe.

Is there any way for me to listen for this error in the parent application, so that I can know when an interactive asset has failed to load due to bandwidth or whatever?

There are try/catches around the content to handle errors thrown by the running interactive asset, but if it never even loads this apparently doesn't trigger those errors.

Anyone got any bright ideas? :)

Comment: Is that `iframe` into the same domain as the main application?

Comment: It is, yes. All content hosted on the same static server.

Comment: When you say: `"the connection was reset", as the content of the iframe.`, you're talking when you try to access iframe.contentWindow.documet etc?

Comment: No, I mean literally it's this chrome screen with the frowning tab icon that shows up: http://imgur.com/AXZGTyn

Comment: Have you tried to use the `beforeunload` event? E.g: `iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() { /* (...) */ });`

Comment: nope, I hadn't, let me give that a try.

Comment: @Myk Does "beforeunload event" worked ?